# Error while running Mapreduce(yarn)from windows eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am running a WordCount program from my eclipse.
I tried with Hadoop1.x it is running fine.
Facing issue while running on hadoop2.x

i tried 
1)added all xml into my classpath.
2)also tried conf.set(), setting xml properties in conf object.

Also in logs it says :-No logs available for container container_1394042163908_0573_01_000001

```
  Application application_1394042163908_0573 failed 2 times due to AM Container for      appattempt_1394042163908_0573_000002 exited with exitCode: 1 due to: Exception from container-launch:
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: /bin/bash: line 0: fg: no job control
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:464)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerEx    ecutor.java:195)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:283)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:79)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)`enter code here`
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the issue, there is a jira for it:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5655

I just added YARNRunner.java & MRApps.java to my project . 
It also reqires to add the following property to mapred-site.xml on the windows box, so that the job launcher knows, that the job runner will be a linux:

```
<property>
<name>mapred.remote.os</name>
<value>Linux</value>
<description>Remote MapReduce framework's OS, can be either Linux or Windows</description>
</property>
```

And MapReduce is running fine now.

Also Copy org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.java into your project.

You can comment out the below line,to remove the winutils.exe Error.
      throw new IOException("Could not locate executable " + fullExeName + " in the Hadoop binaries.");