# Mapreduce job fail when submitted from windows machine

Tags: windows, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to submit a M/R job from windows machine to hadoop cluster on linux. I am using hadoop 2.2.0 (HDP 2.0).

I am getting following error:

```
2014-06-06 08:32:37,684 [main] INFO  Job.monitorAndPrintJob  - Job job_1399458460502_0053 running in uber mode : false
2014-06-06 08:32:37,704 [main] INFO  Job.monitorAndPrintJob  -  map 0% reduce 0%
2014-06-06 08:32:37,717 [main] INFO  Job.monitorAndPrintJob  - Job job_1399458460502_0053 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1399458460502_0053 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1399458460502_0053_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1 due to: Exception from container-launch: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: /bin/bash: line 0: fg: no job control

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)


.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.

java.io.IOException: Job failed!
```

I using configuration taken from the cluster so there should be exact match.

Any hints or clue, what might be wrong?

Thx

Comment: Can you upload the NM log and the job.xml?

Comment: Thx found solution. Btw: where do I find job.xml - we just migrated to hadoop 2 and I am still a bit unfamiliar.

Comment: We are still solving this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044631/running-hadoop-in-standalone-mode-failing-exitcode-1000 with standalone mode. Don't you know if it at least works? Or what might be an issue? Thx a lot

Comment: job.xml will be in your NM local-directory, eg. `<local-dir>/Hadoop/local/usercache/$user/appcache/$appid/$attempt_container_id/job.xml` (easy, heh?). After a while it gets deleted and collected by historyserver somewhere in HDFS. But you'll also find it in the historyserver Web UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. It is officially reported bug

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-4052

with workaround mentioned down in discussion. 
Workaround works fine for me. Seems that those bugs with something resolved on a client side are ever green.

Answer (score 8):

```
conf.set("mapreduce.app-submission.cross-platform", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

I  had a similar issue .Now it is working for me .
Check the below link

[Error while running Mapreduce(yarn)from windows eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872677/error-while-running-mapreduceyarnfrom-windows-eclipse/24098346#24098346)