# Map Reduce Job fails when submitted from Windows to Linux (Cent OS)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I am getting the following error when submitting a map-reduce job from windows to linux.

Container id: container_1422288303092_0045_02_000001

```
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

- The same job works fine from Linux to Linux.
- I have looked at several other stackoverflow posts regarding this issue for example [Related Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872677/error-while-running-mapreduceyarnfrom-windows-eclipse/24098346#24098346) and followed the instructions but it didn't help
- I am using Cloudera hadoop version 2.5 libraries
- I haven't actually applied the patch mentioned in [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-4052) since I imagine it should by now be a part of the distro already
- I have the following properties set in my client side mapred-site.xml:

> ```
>    <property>
>         <name>mapreduce.app-submission.cross-platform</name>
>         <value>true</value>
>     </property>
>     <property>
>         <name>mapreduce.remote.os</name>
>         <value>Linux</value>
>         <description>Remote MapReduce framework's OS, can be either Linux or Windows</description>
>     </property>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

CDH 2.5.1 is different from Apache Hadoop 2.5.1
CDH is on 5.X series now, which supports Apache Hadoop 2.5.0

If you are on Apache Hadoop 2.5.1, you should use Apache's jars. However, if you really are on CDH 2.5.1 you should use CDH 2.5.1 jars and you will have to apply the patch as well.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-4052 indicates 2.4 as the fixed version. It's unlikely it didn't carry over to 2.5

Comment: that's right, if this has been fixed in 2.4 it should be available in 2.5

Comment: are you using a CDH distribution ?

Comment: Wait ! Was this just a typo? Are you on CDH 2.5.1 or Hadoop 2.5?
I hope this is just a typo

Comment: AFAIK, with CDH you do not have Apache Hadoop 2.5.1

Comment: Sorry, yes typo. CDH 5.2